# Hyperlink markdown doesn't work in mobile version

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, opera-mini

I was attempting to type a hyperlink using markdown on my mobile device running Opera Mobile 12.0.1 and for some reason, the link didn't render correctly. However, when I looked up examples of hyperlinks using markdown and copy and pasted them, it did work. Anyone have any idea why that is?

Comment: Where's the example?

Comment: You probably typed it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming [this is the one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/293fab06-5de3-4437-ae00-75067f2f2953/view-source), what you typed isn't a valid URL, since it has no scheme (it has [since been fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10239687/revisions). This has nothing to do with whether you posted this from a phone or not.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was talking about. I didn't know you could find revisions like that, otherwise I would have posted them. If you look at my previous revisions, I tried a few different kinds. Do you have a sense as to why they didn't work?

Comment: All your previous tries had the same issue -- the missing `http://`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that was required... thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

More than likely, as the establishment says, you typed it wrong. I'm pretty sure the markdown links are converted on the server side anyway.

I happen to be using Opera mobile 12.0 to type this, and both syntaxes [`[a](...)`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129930/172958) and [`[b][1]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129930/172958) work fine. Are you sure you didn't have a space, automatically inserted by a paste, perhaps? Markdown can be awfully picky about things like that.

Comment: There's a third syntax too: <http://example.com>